# resp declared and not used in golang

Tags: go

I get this error everytime I try to run the code.
I am unsure as to how to use unused variables in go and how to make the code work without using unused variables. I had to delete an if-else statement for this question to be posted. The issue is as such:
    if (case1) call one url
    else  if (case2) call another url
    else call another url.

Thanks for the help. I tried various hacks but none of them seem to work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rage := rand.Int31() % 3
    var resp *Response
    if rage == 1 {
        resp, _ := http.Get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?            query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=AIzaSyAh4t-qlMYrxnk0XF0Yiu9ZXVFDNfPTCFs")
    } else {
        resp, _ := http.Get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyAh4t-qlMYrxnk0XF0Yiu9ZXVFDNfPTCFs")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp = unused.Item
    fmt.Println("Inside handler")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(body), nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:9999", nil)
}

Output:
C:\go\gowiki\websrevice_citibytes_SOAP.go:233: resp declared and not used
C:\go\gowiki\websrevice_citibytes_SOAP.go:235: resp declared and not used
C:\go\gowiki\websrevice_citibytes_SOAP.go:237: resp declared and not used
```

Comment: Nice blob of unformatted code. Try again.

Comment: just change `resp, _ :=` to `resp, _ =`

Comment: and BTW please do check for errors. and also, why do the `http.Get` twice? just format the url accordingly, and run the request just once.

Comment: sorry for the mistakes. I tried = instead of := and it still refuses to work. The http tiwce is just a requirement for now. We are performance profiling and need such a condition to work before we make a call on using Go instead of Node.js or Java

Comment: if i use = instead of := i get the following error.C:\go\gowiki\websrevice_citibytes_SOAP.go:235: cannot assign *http.Response to r
esp (type *Response) in multiple assignment

Comment: What is unused for? And I think you miss some import, for example: You use ioutil, but there's no "io/ioutil" path in the list of imported packages. Plus there's no package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

`var resp *Response` should be `var res *http.Response`

you should `import "io/ioutil"` if you want to use its `ReadAll` function.

what is `resp = unused.Item` ? It should be removed.

After you fix all those things, as other comments say: Remove the `:` in the lines that assign it to resp:

`resp, _ := http.Get("...")` -> `resp, _ = http.Get("...")`

The error is that using `:=` is creating a new variable `resp`, that overrides the previous one and only lives inside the if scope.

As others suggested, it may be better to just use a string variable with the url and use the if to set that variable.

```
var url string = url1
if cond {
  url = url2
}
resp, err := http.Get(url)
```

Also, **do not ignore errors**

Answer (score -1):

Those strange limitations in Golang Devs team heads are terribly annoying.

Why not to allow people to disable their limitations with options?

Answer is simple: they write the lang for themselves (for guugle), not for the community.

Fortunately, Go is OpenSource and even written in Go.

So, here is a simple patch removing the "declared and not used" or "declared but not used" errors raising:

```
diff --git a/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go b/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go
index 770210f..78c0cbc 100644
--- a/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go
+++ b/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go
@@ -49,10 +49,7 @@ func walk(fn *Node) {
                        if defn.Left.Name.Used() {
                                continue
                        }
-                       yyerrorl(defn.Left.Pos, "%v declared and not used", ln.Sym)
                        defn.Left.Name.SetUsed(true) // suppress repeats
-               } else {
-                       yyerrorl(ln.Pos, "%v declared and not used", ln.Sym)
                }
        }

diff --git a/src/go/types/stmt.go b/src/go/types/stmt.go
index abd9d05..8b15786 100644
--- a/src/go/types/stmt.go
+++ b/src/go/types/stmt.go
@@ -55,6 +55,7 @@ func (check *Checker) funcBody(decl *declInfo, name string, sig *Signature, body
 }

 func (check *Checker) usage(scope *Scope) {
+       return
        var unused []*Var
        for _, elem := range scope.elems {
                if v, _ := elem.(*Var); v != nil && !v.used {
```

(Actual for go1.12)

Unpack a fresh Golang into /usr/local/go and apply the patch.

Then compile:

```
export GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go2
cp -a /usr/local/go /usr/local/go2
cd /usr/local/go/src
sed -e 's#^bash run.bash.*##' -i all.bash
./all.bash
rm -rf /usr/local/go2
unset GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP
```

It's much faster to apply the patch once [per new version] than every time deal with every missed variable.